# Как переделать под адаптивную верстку текущий сайт?

Tags: scss, framework, html, вёрстка, css

Собственно, сабж.
Есть ли у кого опыт такого, что можете посоветовать?
Писать `медиа-запросы` под каждый вопрос — не универсальное решение. :)

Comment: Проценты и/или media запросы. А как вы хотите, прописать два класса и готово?

Comment: @Genson думал с использованием фреймворков, понимаю что не просто, потому и спрашиваю :)

Comment: wtf? каких еще фреймворков? чтобы была одна кнопка - сделай как я хочу?

Comment: @woland Имею ввиду Foundation, Bootstrap etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поменять все значения в пикселях на значения в %

Comment: Вычислять ширину относительно враппера ? Думаете это решение ?

Comment: почему относительно враппера? задать ширину для html,body 100% и вычислять относительно него

Comment: @woland по дизайну, страница фиксированной ширины, вот почему такой вопрос прошел.

Comment: ну вы разберитесь уже, чего вы хотите - адаптивную верстку или фиксированную ширину.

Comment: @woland что вообще подразумеваете под адаптивностью ? Может мы друг друга не понимаем

Comment: скорее всего. для меня адаптивная верстка = "резиновая" верстка.